# Registering theme function in drupal

Tags: 7, theming, hooks

I'm trying to follow this tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-facebook-recent-activity-drupal-module/

But it doesn't render any output with mymodule_node_view, code below:

```
<?php
    /** 
    * Implements hook_node_view(). 
    * 
    * Returns the renderable view of our nodes (pages or articles). 
    * We want to moddify the code so that we add the like button 
    * to our pages. 
    */  
    function fbrecent_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $node->content['fbrecent_additional_field'] = array(
    '#markup' => theme('fbrecent_add_like_button'),
    '#weight' => 10, 
    );
    }

    /** 
    * Implements hook_theme(). 
    * 
    * Just to let Drupal know about our theme function. 
    */  
    function fbrecent_theme()  
    {  
      return array(  
        'fbrecent_add_like_button' => array('variables' => NULL),  
      );  
    }  

    /** 
    * Function to add the desired code to our page. 
    */  
    function theme_fbrecent_add_like_button()  
    {  
        $output = '123';
        return $output;  
    }
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, I've cleared cache as well. Using some string value for #markup renders the content though. So it's issue with the 2 functions, either fbrecent_theme() or theme_fbrecent_add_like_button()

And is there a debugging option somewhere that would output any kind of information of what's going on in the background? Like if it doesn't have said function/hook, it should output some kind of warning or error for me.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there's anything wrong there. As a sanity check, try changing your theme definition to `'fbrecent_add_like_button' => array('variables' => array()),  ` and clear the cache

Comment: Thanks, Clive. I was sure I had cleared cache before, but after clearing it again, it works.